# How to drop queue message when there is no consume?(ActiveMQ)

Tags: queue, activemq-classic

Use ActiveMQ :
Senario:
 Server will send many messages to client through Queue.
 However ,i nedd to drop the message in the queue if there is no consumer(client)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need ActiveMQ to drop all messages in the queue if there is no consumer. I know the topic do like this,however,i have no more than one consumer .

Answer (score 2):

You can use non persistent messaging and the message is dropped if there is no active consumers.

Another alternative could be to use message expiry, so the message expires after X period, if they are not consumed from the queue.

Comment: Thanks. hot to use none persistent ?From the active MQ home page, http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html　when use <broker persistent="false">
</broker> ,This will use This will make the broker use the <memoryPersistenceAdapter>.

Comment: It won't drop the old message if use none persistent when use <broker persistent="false"> </broker>  .Is there something i am wrong?

Comment: @Claus, message persistence affects what happens when the broker restarts, not what happens while it's still online.  Maybe you're thinking of what happens with topics, but queues will keep all messages (persistent or not) until they are consumed by some consumer (or until the broker is restarted if messages are non-persistent).

Answer (score 1):

Set a `JMSExpiration` on each message for some duration (30 seconds? 5 minutes?), and then any message that's not consumed after that amount of time (whether because there's no consumer or because the consumer's running behind) will be sent to the DLQ.  Or if you don't want it in the DLQ, then configure the dead letter strategy to set `processExpired=false` or use a Discarding DLQ Plugin, both documented at http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html.

Comment: If the Producer can't/won't set it... http://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html